# Linux/Debian Java Memory issue

Tags: java, linux, memory, debian, cpu-usage

Hello Stackoverflow Community,

i have a problem with my vServer (hosted by https://host-unlimited.de/).

I'll make a minecraft server network (with MySQL-Server, TeamSpeak³ and apache2-Website)

---

My Problem is Java says:

```
> java -jar spigot.jar
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Cannot create GC thread. Out of system resources.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /cloud/temporary/GunGame-1/hs_err_pid2734.log
```

But the server has enough memory free:

```
> free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         24336       5456      18879        256          0        923
-/+ buffers/cache:       4533      19802
Swap:            0          0          0
```

HTOP (from "apt-get install htop"):

```
> htop
http://prntscr.com/fca7we
```

LSHW(lshw -html):

```
    srv46374
    description: Computer
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: vsyscall64 vsyscall32
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       physical id: 0
     *-memory
          description: System memory
          physical id: 0
          size: 23GiB
     *-cpu
          product: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2650 0 @ 2.00GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 1
          bus info: cpu@0
          width: 64 bits
          capabilities: fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid dca sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx lahf_lm ida arat epb pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid xsaveopt
```

Thanks in advance!

//EDIT: Java Error Log (hs_err_XXX): https://pastebin.com/bkBFKY9Q

//EDIT: ulimit -a

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 515535
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 65536
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 10240
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) unlimited
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

//EDIT:

```
> java -version
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

//EDIT:

```
> sysinfo
------------------ Java Information ------------------
Java Version:    1.8.0_131
Java Vendor:     Oracle Corporation
Java home:       /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
Java classpath:  /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/lib/derby.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/lib/derbynet.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/lib/derbytools.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/lib/derbyoptionaltools.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/lib/derbyclient.jar
OS name:         Linux
OS architecture: amd64
OS version:      2.6.32-openvz-042stab123.2-amd64
Java user name:  root
Java user home:  /root
Java user dir:   /cloud/temporary/GunGame-1
java.specification.name: Java Platform API Specification
java.specification.version: 1.8
java.runtime.version: 1.8.0_131-b11
--------- Derby Information --------
[/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/lib/derby.jar] 10.11.1.2 - (1629631)
[/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/lib/derbytools.jar] 10.11.1.2 - (1629631)
[/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/lib/derbynet.jar] 10.11.1.2 - (1629631)
[/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/lib/derbyclient.jar] 10.11.1.2 - (1629631)
[/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/lib/derbyoptionaltools.jar] 10.11.1.2 - (1629631)
------------------------------------------------------
----------------- Locale Information -----------------
Current Locale :  [English/United States [en_US]]
Found support for locale: [cs]
         version: 10.11.1.2 - (1629631)
Found support for locale: [de_DE]
         version: 10.11.1.2 - (1629631)
Found support for locale: [es]
         version: 10.11.1.2 - (1629631)
Found support for locale: [fr]
         version: 10.11.1.2 - (1629631)
Found support for locale: [hu]
         version: 10.11.1.2 - (1629631)
Found support for locale: [it]
         version: 10.11.1.2 - (1629631)
Found support for locale: [ja_JP]
         version: 10.11.1.2 - (1629631)
Found support for locale: [ko_KR]
         version: 10.11.1.2 - (1629631)
Found support for locale: [pl]
         version: 10.11.1.2 - (1629631)
Found support for locale: [pt_BR]
         version: 10.11.1.2 - (1629631)
Found support for locale: [ru]
         version: 10.11.1.2 - (1629631)
Found support for locale: [zh_CN]
         version: 10.11.1.2 - (1629631)
Found support for locale: [zh_TW]
         version: 10.11.1.2 - (1629631)
------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------
```

//EDIT:

```
cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:       24920064 kB
MemFree:        23222156 kB
Cached:          1002468 kB
Buffers:               0 kB
Active:           716736 kB
Inactive:         686892 kB
Active(anon):     103684 kB
Inactive(anon):   297476 kB
Active(file):     613052 kB
Inactive(file):   389416 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:             0 kB
SwapFree:              0 kB
Dirty:                 8 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:        401160 kB
Shmem:            264064 kB
Slab:              30204 kB
SReclaimable:      16952 kB
SUnreclaim:        13252 kB
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you might be using 32-bit java, try to purge all of them, to find what all the java installs do:

```
dpkg -l java*
```

and then to purge them,

```
sudo apt purge java*
```

For the packages that come from apt use (for specific packages, wildcard * works):

```
apt list --installed <package>
```

and for the whole list:

```
apt list --installed
```

perhaps do

```
sudo apt purge jdk*
```

as well, and then reinstall java directly from oracle's website, or add the repo to apt.

If that doesn't work change the amount of ram Java can use because that could be the problem as well, because jvm is always limited to a max.

[JDK8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

Comment: Doesn't work :/ Java doesn't exists anymore: "> java - -bash: /usr/bin/java: No such file or directory"

Comment: did you reinstall it from the oracle website?

Comment: I'm installing it now with: "sudo apt-get install default-jre && sudo apt-get install default-jdk" (need the jdk)

Comment: I didn't want you to download from default-jre because that inherits open-jdk, but try it.

Comment: I'm downloading it now from the original website... Because i'm stucking at "Unpacking openjdk-7-jdk:amd64 (7u131-2.6.9-2~deb8u1) over (7u131-2.6.9-2~deb8u1)"

Comment: Situation Report?

Comment: Cannot install, remove and other with apt-get, because it always tries to upgrade openjdk-7-jdk:amd64 and stucks at "Unpacking openjdk-7-jdk:amd64 (7u131-2.6.9-2~deb8u1) over (7u131-2.6.9-2~deb8u1) ..." Cannot exit with Ctrl+C only with new terminal and reboot

Comment: every time you try to do anything with apt-get it goes back to trying to unpack openjdk?

Comment: What might have happaned is that you have a damaged package, check /var/cache/apt/archives

Comment: > cd /var/cache/apt/archives > ls >>>> libice-dev_2%3a1.0.9-1+b1_amd64.deb
libpthread-stubs0-dev_0.3-4_amd64.deb
libsm-dev_2%3a1.2.2-1+b1_amd64.deb
libx11-dev_2%3a1.6.2-3_amd64.deb
libx11-doc_2%3a1.6.2-3_all.deb
libxau-dev_1%3a1.0.8-1_amd64.deb
libxcb1-dev_1.10-3+b1_amd64.deb
libxdmcp-dev_1%3a1.1.1-1+b1_amd64.deb
libxt-dev_1%3a1.1.4-1+b1_amd64.deb
lock
openjdk-7-jdk_7u131-2.6.9-2~deb8u1_amd64.deb
partial
x11proto-core-dev_7.0.26-1_all.deb
x11proto-input-dev_2.3.1-1_all.deb
x11proto-kb-dev_1.0.6-2_all.deb
xorg-sgml-doctools_1%3a1.11-1_all.deb
xtrans-dev_1.3.4-1_all.deb

Comment: move them all out of there, and try again, what you could also try doing is downloading open-jdk (that specific version) manually from the internet, and the replacing it on the archiver folder.

Comment: Is there a way to completely delete the version?

Comment: I'm telling you to move it out of the directory for safety reasons, the version is not installed just yet, you are going to move them out from there so you can try it again, right now I'm trying to fix your apt instead of worrying about the server, apt first, server after.

Comment: So now you gotta try installing java runtime environment and java dev kit, I would recommend, once again using the ones that come directly from oracle

Answer (score 0):

According to your log you are using 32 bit Java. Due to it there is a problem that the process size is limited.

Pls, switch to 64 bit on.

Comment: Java 64bit is installed -java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)

Answer (score 0):

### First hunch

How much heap do you give your JVM? Do you limit it at all?
Try runnig the following command:

```
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep Heap
```

... and find things like **HeapSizePerGCThread**, **InitialHeapSize** and **MaxHeapSize** to see what your JVM claims as its defaults in your particular deployment.

Then try to marry that with the result of `# ulimit -a`. Hopefully you can find some limit which your JVM is exceeding, in which case just add appropriate flags to the command line to rein JVM in a bit.

### Second (more detailed) hunch

In your log we see: `CPU:total 32 (initial active 8) (8 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core)` - nice machine!

The question is how many processors does Java see upon start. `/proc/cpuinfo` lists 8 processors, but each with 16 siblings (hyperthreaded).

If you could run very simple class first, you could find out exactly:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
}
```

I appreciate that even this class might fail to launch... If my theory is right run it per following command line:

```
java --XX:ParallelGCThreads=2 com.test.HowManyProcessors
```

... where the last param is that simple class' name.

If it runs, then we are on the right track and it will show you how many processors Java can play with. 
If this number is big, try starting your Java like this:

```
java -XX:ParallelGCThreads=<a_number_of_gc_threads> -jar spigot.jar
```

By default if number of processors **N <= 8** then parallel GC will use just as many. For **N > 8** available processors, the number of GC threads will be computed as **3+5N/8**.

Therefore it is entirely possible that if your machine gives Java many CPUs to play with, Java is trying to start quite few threads just for GC, which could hit platform limits and surprisingly result in `insufficient memory - can't create GC thread`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: a comment why this got downvoted would be much appreciated!